# I just updated my iOS Project Name, and now the "appName-Info.plist" file is "missing"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I just updated the name of my project, by changing it in the identity field (and then choosing "rename project") Now when I try to build my project I get a build failure stating that the 'appname-info.plist' file can not be located because it does not exist.

I can see the file exists, it is in the project and the folder, and the path is correct.

I have tried deleting the file and re-adding it, I have opened it to verify it is not corrupt, I am not sure what else to do.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed when I changed the file "AppName-info.plist" back to the original app name...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your Target -> Build Settings -> and find "Info.plist file" field. Make sure it's correct.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, but the information there is all correct.